# RequestPermission bug:Can only use lower 16 bits for requestCode

Tags: android, android-permissions

My android app needs some permissions, so I used the following code according to the [developer's Guide](https://developer.android.google.cn/training/permissions/requesting#request-permission).But it went wrong.

```
ActivityResultLauncher launcher = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission(), result -> {
    if(result){
        Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: Permission Granted");
            }
        else{
            Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: No Permission");
        }
    });
launcher.launch(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
```

Exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can only use lower 16 bits for requestCode
```

Why is the "recommended" method wrong?

Comment: why don't you just use the simple `requestPermissions(...)` call instead?

Comment: I just started learning, so I wrote it according to the guide.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not in THIS code. RequestCode is valid from 0 up to 32766 but when your code (or a 3rd library) calls "...requestPermissions(.., .., **requestCode**)" (maybe in your "*launch(...)*" method) the "*requestCode*" goes outside that range.